# Let $p$ be an arbitrary prime number and $G$ be an abelian group, how is $pG$ defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, functors

> Let $p$ be a fixed prime in $\Bbb Z$ and $Ab$ represent the category of abelian groups.  Define a functor $F : Ab
> \rightarrow Ab$ by $F(G) = G/pG$ and $F(f) = x + pG \rightarrow f(x) +
> pH$ (where $f:G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism)

What does $pG$ mean for an abelian group?  I am familiar with the notation $aG = \{ag : g \in G\}$, but $G$ isn't specified to be an integer group which would be compatible with a prime $p$.

Comment: For example $3G=G+G+G,$ the set of sums of three elements from $G,$ if $G$ written additively.

Comment: @coffeemath So if $G$ is the group ($\{$odd number, even number$\}$, multiplication), then $3G$ is the set of all $x * y * z$ where $x,y,z \in G$?

Comment: Yes, if the asterisk is the group operation.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  The definition of $aG$ you give in your question makes sense since $G$ is an abelian group (i.e., $\mathbb{Z}$-module).